winget not finding OpenSSL
I want to install OpenSSL using winget and am following https://winget.run/pkg/ShiningLight/OpenSSL (installing Git is not an option, I have gone through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625283/how-to-install-openssl-in-windows-10).
When I run,
winget search openssl

I get,

But when I try to install it using
winget install -e --id ShiningLight.OpenSSL --silent


Also, when I go to https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL-3_2_1.msi, its indeed a 404.

The correct link to the file is https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL-3_3_1.msi contact the maintainer WinGet repository and have them fix it. You can use a manual downloaded installer and still use WinGet. The instructions are accurate but the repository is misconfigured. We can’t help fix that. I suggest just using a WinGet alternative or install it with the .msi manually

You can use https://winget.pro/ to setup a private WinGet repository for the time being.

WinGet version of the software is simply outdated. The version on the website got updated to 3.2.2, with old installer deleted.

You can find all the package sources here. The one you're trying to update is here. As is it can be seen, manual pull requests are needed for the version to be bumped. And there isn't any for 3.2.2 yet.
So if you want to install that specific minor version specifically with WinGet, you either wait or submit a pull request with new version yourself. Othwerise just install it manually.

I looked at this problem probably for 3 hours. I didn’t see once notice the version being offered wasn’t actually available on the website I thought the path to the file was missing a / but a fifth look at the path on the website proved that to be incorrect. Nice Catch!
